# kernel update 3.19.0-51 breaks nvidia 304.xx Xubuntu 14.04.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel, xorg

update to Linux version 3.19.0-51-generic kills nv304

kernel.log

```
[   19.924934] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  304.131  Sun Nov  8 21:43:33 PST 2015
[   19.950678] init: failsafe main process (879) killed by TERM sign
```

kern.log

```
[   19.918744] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
```

Comment: How did you install the driver? and why do you use 304?

Answer (score 0):

I believe every time when you upgrade your kernel and if the modules like graphics card driver are not upgraded then one need to manually do `apt-get install`

the nvidia driver.
If you were using nvidia driver - you can do

```
apt-get install nvidia-361
```

(after adding the ppa and doing update like this)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

I have often seen in the logs when i am doing apt-get install for nvidia drivers - it builds the module for the current kernel also. My answer is based on that information only.

As somebody suggested to me in this forum - may be you need to take the latest nvidia driver(361) if that supports your nvidia graphics card.
You can check whether nvidia-361 is the [right driver](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/98373/en-us) for your graphics card or not(if it is supporting your graphics card or not)

Comment: "I believe every time .." Nope. That's what DKMS is for. If it isn't working, that's a bug, and installing again won't help.

Comment: that did not work.

Comment: @GalenThurber. What was the error, screen shots any?